# Почему мой wordpress не работает без функций в Allow from all в htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Как грамотно составить **htaccess**, что бы все было как надо!
Мой хостинг не хочет выполнять post запросы если в **htaccess** не будет этого

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

То есть, если нету этих конфигураций сразу ошибка

> 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

Так мой **htaccess** выглядит сейчас!
Это нормально? Если нет, прошу помочь с правильным решением.

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
 
# BEGIN WordPress
# Директивы (строки) между `BEGIN WordPress` и `END WordPress`
# созданы автоматически и подлежат изменению только через фильтры WordPress.
# Сделанные вручную изменения между этими маркерами будут перезаписаны.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: У вас на хостинге должен работать стандартный htaccess: https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/ Если не работает - меняйте хостинг срочно

Comment: @KAGGDesign Я бы с удовольствием, но не могу!

Comment: Пишите хостеру, это их проблема. Здесь гадать можно бесконечно.